# How to solve NSViewController/ NSView error in connect the action with target?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have some Default NSViewController. In it I have code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // Do view setup here.

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];

    if(![defaults boolForKey:@"isLoggedIn"]){


        NSLog(@"Not logged in... Loading settings");

        NSViewController *settings = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:settings.view];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Logged in... Loading inbox");
        NSViewController *inbox = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Inbox" bundle:nil];

        [self.view addSubview:inbox.view];
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

That code works it loads view depends on that NSUserDefaults.

**But when try to declare something in lets say Inbox.m/Inbox.h I am geting this error:**

```
Could not connect the action testView: to target of class NSViewController
```

In Inbox.m I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"Inbox loaded.");

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do view setup here.
}
```

**And that NSLog is never executed**. I want to have several nibs and different NSViewController connected to it.

My guess is that I am adding subviews wrong way. It is like visual elements are there and nothing else.

Comment: got this. see answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by:

```
    Inbox *inbox = [[Inbox alloc] initWithNibName:@"Inbox" bundle:nil];
    _viewController = inbox;

    //Where _viewController is 
    NSViewController *_viewController; 

    //defined in 
   @interface Default : NSViewController{
       NSViewController *_viewController; 
   }
```

Now everything works ok.